# Javascript pattern for dynamically importing "plugin" code from a URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins

I am trying to design a system that uses plugin modules, these modules must include code. I don't want to bundle all of these modules in with my main code (React/Webpack) as they may be large in size and number. The code/URL will be of the same origin/domain. I note the module system is not designed to handle URLs so I am wondering how to get this to work.

My first intuition is to just download the code and eval it but, like everyone, I have been conditioned from birth to regard eval as evil. That said, I'm not sure I have any choice here. Do I? Is there a better pattern/technique for accomplishing this? Maybe leveraging webpack?

edit: So it turns out React has an approved proposal for this functionality in the works. Thanks to @Davin Tryon for cluing me in to the vernacular...
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/code-splitting

Comment: So you want JS to load when the app is running? Can you server render the code so the client can specify a callback like with [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)?

Comment: you should look at next.js: https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/lazy-loading-modules.  The concept you are looking for is 'code-splitting'.